# How to find the following DFT?

Tags: discrete-signals, dft, homework, exam

Let $x[n] = \cos(\frac{\pi}{8}n)$ and $X(k) = \text{DFT}_{16} \{ x[n]\}$

In order to find $X(k)$ I write out the DFT sum:

$$X(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j2\pi kn/N} = \sum_{n=0}^{15} \cos(\frac{\pi}{8}n) e^{-j2\pi kn/16} $$

I could expand the $\cos(\cdot)$ as two complex exponentials inside the sum but that would make the computation rather tedious.

However, if we expand it before jumping into the summation we see that:

$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{8}n) = 0.5e^{j\pi n/8}+0.5e^{-j\pi n/8}$$

Which is just the 16 Pt IDFT of $0.5 \cdot \delta[k-1] + 0.5\cdot \delta[k+1]$ (Properties table in $\textbf{FSP 2014 Vetterli et al Pg 256}$).

At this stage I am not sure how to proceed with handling this IDFT and getting the $\text{DFT}_{16}$ of the original $x[n]$ although I do see some similarities between this and the duality property of the CTFT which makes me think that perhaps if I multiply my IDFT with $N=16$ I should get my desired DFT but I am not sure.

Sidenote: What if the function was changed to $\cos(\frac{\pi}{16}n)$ or $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}n)$. Would we still handle it the same way?

$\textbf{Edit:}$
Attempt at a solution for the sidenote, $x[n] = \cos\frac{\pi}{16}n$:

Let $x[n] = \cos\frac{\pi}{16}n = 0.5e^{j\pi n/16}+0.5e^{-j\pi n/16}$

Split the DFT sum into two parts:

$$ \frac 12 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{j\frac{\pi}{16}n}e^{-j\pi/8 kn} = \frac 12 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{j\frac{\pi}{8}n(\frac 12 - k)} = \frac 12 \frac{1 - (e^{j\frac{\pi}{8}(\frac 12 - k)})^{16}}{1-e^{j\frac{\pi}{8}(\frac 12 - k)}}$$

$$ \frac 12 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-j\frac{\pi}{16}n}e^{-j\pi/8 kn} = \frac 12 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-j\frac{\pi}{8}n(\frac 12 + k)} = \frac 12 \frac{1 - (e^{-j\frac{\pi}{8}(\frac 12 + k)})^{16}}{1-e^{-j\frac{\pi}{8}(\frac 12 + k)}}$$

Upper one equals $\frac{1}{1-e^{j\pi /16}\cdot e^{-j\pi/8 k}}$

And lower one equals $\frac{1}{1-e^{j\pi /16}\cdot e^{j\pi/8 k}}$

How can I combine the two to get the final result?

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/x4huk3g) is a visual representation of the DFT in question. Just keep in mind that the shift to the left represented by $\delta[k+1]$ is a circular shift. Whatever falls off, comes back up on the other side!

Comment: Thank you! By the way, shouldn't the third plot have $n$ as its x-axis label?

Comment: Yes you are correct. It should be 'n' instead of 'k'

Comment: I see. Also, what about handling functions like $\cos(\frac{\pi}{16}n)$ in this fashion?

Comment: @AcerbicNarcissist hm, you're asking this for a reason. What do you think would be different?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well, firstly the IDFT doesn't stay the same because the IDFT size changes, no? Secondly, the signal itself can be expressed as: $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{N}n)$ where $N$ is now 32 but the DFT size is still 16...

Comment: hm, you didn't say the IDFT would change, so it wouldn't. And your math seems right, so, what *exactly* is the problem then? It's a bit different than in the case where N is a divisor of the DFT length, but that just means you need to think a little harder what you're observing here!

Comment: Ok, so in the case of $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{2N}n)$ to represent $\cos(\frac{\pi}{16}n)$ our sequence size is still $N=16$ and our DFT size is also still 16. So now the expansion: $$\cos(\frac{\pi}{16}n) = 0.5e^{j\pi n/16}+0.5e^{-j\pi n/16}$$ is the 32-Pt IDFT of $0.5 \cdot \delta[k-1] + 0.5\cdot \delta[k+1]$, no? So, shouldn't this fundamentally change the problem?

Comment: no, it's not the 32-Point-DFT! Don't confuse the DFT with the Euler way of writing a cosine.

Comment: Could you please write what you think the solution is for $x[n] = cos(\frac{\pi}{16} n)$ as an answer? As per my understanding the Euler expansion is separate from DFT but the result we get can be expressed as the IDFT/DFT of two shifted impulses like in DTFT or CTFT, right?

Comment: only in the special case that their normalized frequency is a divisor of the DFT length, as you noticed! You need to realize that you're not really transforming the cosine, in general, but a *windowed* version of the cosine. The window is exactly of DFT length. You multiply your cosine in time domain with that rectangular window function. The keyword that I *bet* you're being led to learn here is **spectral leakage**.

Comment: Yes, we have covered spectral leakage (or just leakage as I remember it) in class, regarding circular convolution though. This particular exercise is from a past exam that I do not have the solutions of, hence, the exam tag.  Isn't that windowed version that you mention just the difference between DFT and DTFT? Where DFT is the sampling of the DTFT and the truncation of the first period going from $[0, N-1]$...

Comment: To combine your last values, utilize the linearity of the DFT: $F(x[n]+y[n])=X[k]+Y[k]$. Simply add the two values for every value of $k$. Keep in mind the output of the DFT is in general a complex value, but may come out to be purely real if the phase is zero or $\pi$.